# Different order of results in DBpedia through SNORQL vs. SERVICE query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, linked-data

I am trying to retrieve some data about movies from DBpedia. This is my query:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT *
{{SELECT *

WHERE {
SERVICE<http://dbpedia.org/sparql>{
?movie dcterms:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_films> ;
        a onto:Film ;
        rdfs:label ?title ;
        dbpedia2:gross ?revenue .

?movie onto:starring ?actorUri .
?actorUri rdfs:label ?actor .

OPTIONAL {
  ?movie onto:imdbId ?imdbId .
}
BIND(xsd:integer(?revenue) as ?intRevenue) .
FILTER ((datatype(?revenue) = 'http://dbpedia.org/datatype/usDollar') && (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?title), 'en')) && (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?actor), 'en'))) .
}
}
}}
ORDER BY DESC (?intRevenue)
LIMIT 40000
OFFSET 0
```

Running this query on `http://dbpedia.org/snorql/` (without the SERVICE keyword) returns the correct result. However, doing so from a third party triplestore doesn't yield the same order (ex: Hobbit and Lord of the Rings are missing).

What do I need to change in the query to get identical results?

Comment: DBpedia has a default limit of 10000 and your ODER BY is not propagated to the SERVICE query, thus, you can indeed get different results.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this limitation?

Comment: I don't think so. Any remote query, and that's what is basically done when using a SERVICE close to a remote endpoint will suffer from the maximum resultset that is returned by the remote endpoint. So it would be the task of the federated query engine to handle this, but I'm not aware of any implementation. Which API resp. triple store do you use?

Comment: The best way to overcome this limitation is to have [your own DBpedia mirror](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015), on which you can set your own limits (including none), and which you can then use as either your primary or remote data store and/or query engine.

Comment: May be frame this as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to overcome this specific limitation is to have [your own DBpedia mirror](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015), on which you can set your own limits (including none), and which you can then use as either your primary or remote data store and/or query engine.

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) provides the [public DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), produces [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) and the [DBpedia Mirror AMI](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015), and employs me.)